# What benefit has the "sub main ... &main();" approach (sub-main-pattern) in Perl?

Tags: perl, program-entry-point

A few years back, I have adopted the following "pattern" for all except the most simple of my Perl scripts: (I don't even remember where I saw it first, it certainly wasn't my genuine idea.)

```
use strict;
...
sub main {
  ...
}
... possibly more subs ...

... at the end of the file:
#############
# Call main #
&main();
#############
```

Is there any benefit to this? I find the code a little cleaner, but otherwise I'm not sure this has any purpose other that to make the C programmer in me happy :-)

Any insights from Perl experts and power users appreciated. (I am certainly neither)

Comment: I appease my inner C programmer on occasion, too. But I tend to put the call to main() up front, before defining (but after declaring) any subs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a known idiom to limit scope. This is discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/1183876#comment-1012787 ﬀ. and http://use.perl.org/comments.pl?sid=43991&cid=70918 ﬀ.

Comment: Nice link. `exit main();` seems to make even more sense than my approach. (or does it?)

Answer (score 7):

It provides a scope to avoid accidentally using the wrong variables in subs. `{ ... }` would also do this, but using a sub allows the main code to be placed at the top of the file while still executing other initialisation code in the file.

Personally, I've have used

```
{
   ...  # Extract command line switches from @ARGV
   ...  # Perform input validation
   exit(main(@ARGV));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Benefit? No, not unless you need to re-use the main sub. In some cases it might perhaps ease readability, but I doubt it.

One thing that is different is that commands such as:

```
my $arg = shift;
```

Will affect `@_` instead of `@ARGV`, and `@ARGV` will not automatically be passed on to `main()`. `@ARGV` will still be visible inside the sub, but you will have to shift it explicitly `shift @ARGV`.

Comment: I find that `@ARGV` is easily accessible in my sub main (`$ARGV[0]` etc ...) - did I misunderstand you?

Comment: It is global, so it will work anywhere, what I meant was that it is not passed on as an argument to `main()`. But perhaps that is irrelevant. ;) If it was passed on, `shift` inside the sub would have the same functionality, as it would indirectly shift `@ARGV`

Comment: Nice info. I didn't even know that shift implicitly worked on @ARGV in the "global" context :-)

Comment: There are many little tricks to learn about perl. I thought I knew much when I found SO a few weeks ago. Turns out I didn't, and I learn something new every day.

Comment: @TLP: very true, I've gained much knowledge answering questions here.

Answer (score 3):

One advantage might be that it makes it easier to turn your program into a [modulino](http://drdobbs.com/web-development/184416165).

Answer (score 1):

Having done a lot of Perl I'd say it's just something that makes you happy. I doubt it's any faster or slower.

Just to make my answer somewhat useful I will point out that you don't need the `&` on your sub call. `&` makes `@_` visible to the sub, but empty parens negates that.

Comment: `&` doesn't cause Perl to pass the value of `$_` to a subroutine. It makes current `@_` visible to the called subroutine.

Comment: `&NAME()` does not pass on `@_`, it merely overrides the prototypes of the sub. It passes an empty list, as denoted by `()`

Comment: @TLP: I was talking about the `&NAME` syntax, in the context of the answer

Comment: @eugene I figured as much, however, with the syntax in the question, I felt it was a valid clarification, so as not to confuse the issue.

Comment: `&` disables prototypes. `&name;` and `goto &name;` don't localise `@_`, but that's entirely independent.